# NEAR Lake Indexer - Stuck on "#9820210 - Waiting for peers"

Tags: nearprotocol

So I was trying to use the Near Lake Indexer but after completing every step, when I ran

```
./target/release/near-lake --home ~/.near/mainnet run --endpoint https://my-endpoint  --bucket my-bucket --region us-east-1 --stream-while-syncing sync-from-latest
```

there is nothing other than

```
INFO stats: # 9820210 Waiting for peers 0 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 0%, Mem: 32.8 MB
```

Why is it trying to fetch block 9820210 but not the latest one, even though I passed in "sync-from-latest"?

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/near/near-lake-indexer#custom-s3-storage

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the standard nearcore network sync procedures: https://github.com/near/near-lake-indexer#syncing

```
INFO stats: # 9820210 Waiting for peers 0 peers ⬇ 0 B/s ⬆ 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 0%, Mem: 32.8 MB
```

This means that your node does not have the network state backup, and it waits to get synced (why it is not happening is not clear to me, and needs to be asked on https://github.com/near/nearcore by providing them with the means to reproduce the issue running `neard` instead of the indexer).

> Why is it trying to fetch block 9820210 but not the latest one, even though I passed in "sync-from-latest"?

`stats` log is reported by nearcore, which reports the most recent synced block on the node.